# Chromecast is calling http URL 3 times for the same content

Tags: chromecast

When I send a http url of a content to the Chromecast, it is calling the URL 3 times saying that secure content should be sent. I am wondering whether some of experts can help me here. The debug console on chromecast displays "content should also be loaded over https"

1. Is there a way to force chromecast not to try 3 times, as the performance is really bad (image is displayed in phases)
2. When I send a https URL to the content (using a self-signed cert), chromecast is not even calling the server to fetch the content.

Can anyone help me make progress?

Comment: Are you using your own custom receiver or are you using the default media receiver or styled media receiver?

Comment: In addition, self signed certs are not accepted so you need to have one signed by an authority known to Chrome.